# OpenWeatherApi Empty Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function getJSON(){
        document.write("jquery loaded");
        $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Thanjavur&APPID=2afad0c08fba13710457596c4f75921f",function(json){
            document.write(JSON.stringify(json));
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick = "getJSON()">Get Data</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to use Open Weather Api to get the local Weather... but i keep getting an emoty page. What am i doing wrong here.

Comment: i also tried taking the JSON object directly and then printing as a string... That gave me a error...   such as this   {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"[Exception... \"Failure\"  nsresult: \"0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)\"  location: \"JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 4\"  data: no]"}

Comment: i try this code but json is showing in screen.Can you explain in more detail the error

Comment: which browser you are using

Comment: If you paste that string directly in the browser, it returns an invalid API key.  You might want to start with that.

Comment: Also works fine for me. Where are you running this code from? localhost?

Comment: @durbnpoisn - no it doesn't. I copied his entire html and opened it chrome. Worked fine, returned data from API.

Comment: @Starscream...  You can't really say, "no it doesn't".  Because YES, it did!  It didn't happen for you, and that's great.  But if it happened for me, it could be happening for him.  And every little bit of troubleshooting helps.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - if you copy the string with the trailing `"` at the end, or missing off some characters,  then yes, you get invalid API key response. But that is an error of copying, not a problem with his API key. Maybe try it again.

Comment: I'm running this in mozilla firefox. I also tried it in edge. Dont have chrome at the moment but will try in that as well..

Comment: @durbnpoisn-As for the invalid API key... u need to create a account in openweather and get your own api key... other wise it shows invalid.

Comment: @Starscream1984- yes i am running it from localhost.

Comment: I tried it in chrome and it works. Is there any way to make it work in Mozilla??